# Trying to replace content in all anchors, but content not being replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace all the content, depending on what it is, with a corresponding unicode character in all anchors that are descendants of the class nav ( .nav a ).

But this javascript / jQuery doesn't seem to be doing anything.

It is not showing any errors, just nothing is happening.

What am I doing wrong and how can I replace certain text with other certain text with javascript / jQuery ?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var navigationLinks = $('.nav a');
for(var i=0; i < navigationLinks.length; i++){
    var thisLink = navigationLinks.eq(i);
    switch(thisLink.html()){
        case "About":
            thisLink.html().replace(/About/g,'&#xe00f;');

        case "Work":
            thisLink.html().replace(/Work/g,'&#xe010');

        case "CV":
            thisLink.html().replace(/CV/g,'&#xe00c');

        case "Resume":
            thisLink.html().replace(/Resume/g,'&#xe00d;');

        case "down":
            thisLink.html().replace(/down/g,'&#xe00d;');

        case "Mail":
            thisLink.html().replace(/Mail/g,'&#xe011;');

        case "Dribbble":
            thisLink.html().replace(/Dribbble/g,'&#xe015;');

        case "GooglePlus":
            thisLink.html().replace(/GooglePlus/g,'&#xe012;');

        case "Facebook":
            thisLink.html().replace(/Facebook/g,'&#xe013;');

        case "Twitter":
            thisLink.html().replace(/Twitter/g,'&#xe014');

        default:
            thisLink.html().replace(thisLink.html(),thisLink.html());
    }
}
});
```

And here is a live example of the code where I tried it, but it doesn't work.
The text inside the anchors inside the .nav class is still the original text and not the unicodes: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/replace/index.html

Comment: use break; in each case else always default option works

Comment: oh, somehow I thought in javascript switch you don't have to use break.

Comment: Use `$('.nav a').each`, rather than repeatedly calling `.eq`.

Answer (score 2):

`html()` **gets** the `innerHTML`, while `html("string")` **sets** the `innerHTML`. You have to re-set the value; you can't just call `replace` on a string.

As an example, you can redo your `case` statements to follow this convention:

```
var myHtml = thisLink.html();
switch (myHtml) {
    case "About":
        thisLink.html(myHtml.replace(/About/g, '&#xe00f;'));
        break;
```

or use this for the `.html()` call:

```
thisLink.html(function (i, oldVal) {
    return oldVal.replace(/About/g, '&#xe00f;');
});
```

Also, you need to include `break` for each `case`, to prevent the next block from executing.

In addition, the jQuery way to loop through the matched elements is with `.each()`, not a for loop (although still very valid). So something like:

```
$('.nav a').each(function () {
    var thisLink = $(this);
    var myHtml = thisLink.html();
    // The rest of the code...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7hKTs/

Note that you could do this more concisely, but I wanted to retain your original structure so that you could see the corrections I made in context.

- Added breaks in the `switch` statement.
- Added proper assignment of html after `replace()`. `html()` is a method; you need to do something with its return value (such as assign it to a variable).

**Example 1:** `thisLink.html().replace(/About/g,'&#xe00f;');`. This gets the HTML of the link, calls `replace()` on it, but the return value of `replace()` is unused. This will not have the desired effect.

**Example 2:** `thisLink.html(thisLink.html().replace(/About/g,'&#xe00f;'));` This now passes the modified HTML to the `html()` method. In this single line, it both gets *and* sets the HTML by calling `html()` with and without arguments.

**Example 3:** However, example #2 is very verbose/repetitive when used multiple times, so we can do something simpler:

```
// get the value
var html = thisLink.html();

// handle any number of cases here

// note the assignment of the return value of html()
html = html.replace(/About/g, '&#xe00f;');

// set the value
thisLink.html(html);
```

See also: http://api.jquery.com/html/

**Full Example**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var navigationLinks = $('.nav a');
    for (var i = 0; i < navigationLinks.length; i++) {
        var thisLink = navigationLinks.eq(i);
        var html = thisLink.html();

        switch (html) {
            case "About":
                html = html.replace(/About/g, '&#xe00f;');
                break;
            case "Work":
                html = html.replace(/Work/g, '&#xe010');
                break;
            case "CV":
                html = html.replace(/CV/g, '&#xe00c');
                break;
            case "Resume":
                html = html.replace(/Resume/g, '&#xe00d;');
                break;
            case "down":
                html = html.replace(/down/g, '&#xe00d;');
                break;
            case "Mail":
                html = html.replace(/Mail/g, '&#xe011;');
                break;
            case "Dribbble":
                html = html.replace(/Dribbble/g, '&#xe015;');
                break;
            case "GooglePlus":
                html = html.replace(/GooglePlus/g, '&#xe012;');
                break;
            case "Facebook":
                html = html.replace(/Facebook/g, '&#xe013;');
                break;
            case "Twitter":
                html = html.replace(/Twitter/g, '&#xe014');
                break;
        }

        thisLink.html(html);
    }
});
```

---

### Alternative

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7hKTs/5/

I like this approach better because it takes the markup almost completely out of the script. Instead, we use `data-*` attributes to store the alternative HTML string.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-alt="&#xe00f;">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-alt="&#xe010;">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-alt="&#xe00c;">CV</a></li>
        <!-- etc -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav a').each(function () {
        var obj = $(this);
        obj.html(obj.data("alt"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, how could you do it more concisely?

Comment: I'd probably build a map of the key/replacement and omit the switch altogether. Also as `meager` suggested, an `each()` may be a little cleaner.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you very much for the help. I hadn't known about using a map before. Except, I am getting an unexpected string error on line 10. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/theirf/5370039
I can't see anything different between that line and the lines that aren't throwing errors.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `switch`/`case` work with exact matches already, the global RegExp and `replace` are actually repeating work:

```
switch(thisLink.html()){
    case "About":
        thisLink.html('&#xe00f;');
        break;

    case "Work":
        thisLink.html('&#xe010;');
        break;

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be far easier to work with a replacement map and iterate over each anchor using `.each()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var navigationLinks = $('.nav a'),
    replacements = {
        "About": '&#xe00f;',
        "Work": '&#xe010',
        "CV": '&#xe00c',
        "Resume": '&#xe00d;',
        "down": '&#xe00d;',
        "Mail": '&#xe011;',
        "Dribbble": '&#xe015;',
        "GooglePlus": '&#xe012;',
        "Facebook": '&#xe013;',
        "Twitter": '&#xe014'
    };

    navigationLinks.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        txt = replacements[$this.text()];

        if (txt) {
            $this.text(txt);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about .each(). Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I would though my 2 cents in also.  Same concept as the others mentioned.  This example use a map and the $.each function of jquery.

```
var hashMap = { 'About' : '&#xe00f;', 'Work' : '&#xe010;', 'CV' : '&#xe00c;' }

$.each($('.nav a'), function(index, value) { 
        var x = $(value).html(); 
        $(value).html(hashMap[x]); 
} );
```

Comment: A map sounds interesting. I might use that. Thank you.